# Confusing neomodels `unique=True` behaviour

Tags: python, neo4j

The behaviour of the `unique` property on `neomodel.StructuredNode` is a bit confusing to me.

Can anyone point me to the docs where this is explained? Or let me know what I'm misunderstanding?

The model:

```
class Person(neomodel.StructuredNode):

    uuid = neomodel.UniqueIdProperty()

    legacy_external_id = neomodel.StringProperty(unique=True, required=False)
```

Not all `Person` instances will have this "legacy_external_id", but nonetheless where it exists it needs to be unique.

The above code seems to me the to fit that description.

Yet in practice the output is:

```
In[]: p = Person(legacy_external_id='u12345')
In[]: p.save()
Out[]: < Person: {'uuid': '7d7e5c2224d647e9a87d23b9cb1c4153', 'legacy_external_id': 'u12345'} >

In[]: p = Person(legacy_external_id='u12345')
In[]: p.save()
Out[]: < Person: {'uuid': 'ed7690f8f28b4cf288c35d2130a2e6e4', 'legacy_external_id': 'u12345'} >

In[]: p = Person(legacy_external_id='u12345')
In[]: p.save()
Out[]: < Person: {'uuid': '7393a4b5022d40d8aca002cecac9b124', 'legacy_external_id': 'u12345'} >
```

Just merrily proliferating nodes (without error or warning) is not the behaviour I expected.

I'm fine to write my own validation, but before I ploughed ahead to do that I'm interested to understand my miscomprehension.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be `unique_index=True`, not `unique=True`.

Also, the current version of Neomodel does not support the combination of `unique_index=True` and `required=False`. If a property is set as unique, then it is automatically treated as required as well (presumably because otherwise, you could have two or more Nodes with null property, which wouldn't be unique).

Comment: Thanks for this I figured it out, but decided to leave the question up anyway. At this stage validation and integrity checking with graphs is harder than RDBMS ..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was caused by not having the indexing and constraints instructions installed as explained here: https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#enable-automatic-index-and-constraint-creation

```py
from neomodel import install_labels
install_labels(Person)
```